# DB structure for a blog service

Tags: database

We are developing a blog service similar to the Blogspot. We are going to have more than 1000 blogs.

we have two choices:

1. Create a new table for each user like what Wordpress does
2. Save all users in a table (separate each user with the user_id)

Any idea what would be the best structure to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why WordPress actually does that, but the usual thing would be to have one table covering many users.

Comment: Option 1 is batsh*t insane ... so I'd go for 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think second one is best

- Save all users in a table (separate each user with user_id)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how will you use the data.
Most common is to store one type of data in one table. So one table for users, one table for blog entries, etc. In most cases that would be efficient enough and easy to query.